# JavaxMail sending PDF as a File

Tags: java, smtp, jakarta-mail

Hi StackOverflow Community,

I'm trying to fix a problem that I have with Javax Mail, I have an SMTP Service that send mails with attachments. I send the PDF correctly and if I look at the email it shows that it's a PDF Document but when I press download save it as a File and cand be opened by acrobat reader properly.

Here's the code where I set the document

```
...
    byte[] bytearray = "This is a PDF Document".getBytes();
    ByteArrayDataSource bds = new ByteArrayDataSource(bytearray, "application/pdf");
    attachmentBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(bds));
    attachmentBodyPart.setFileName("prueba");
    attachmentBodyPart.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
    multipart.addBodyPart(attachmentBodyPart);
...
```

And here's the images of the mail received

[image: email received]

Here's how I download it.
[image: Download as a file]

WHat should I do? What I am missing?

Thanks in advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are simply sending text as a pdf file, which as expected will not be a valid pdf that can be opened by any pdf reader.

You can use some library like iText to create a valid pdf file and then attach it to email.

Sample code using itext:

```java
Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("iTextHelloWorld.pdf"));

document.open();
Font font = FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.COURIER, 16, BaseColor.BLACK);
Chunk chunk = new Chunk("Hello World", font);

document.add(chunk);
document.close();
```

For further reading : [PDFs in java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-pdf-creation)

Comment: As a service, I recieve the data as ByteArray and could be pdf, txt or other type, there's no simple way to convert this bytearray to the type they want it and send it? Witouth generating a pdf in the server or using a third party library

Comment: If you know the type of ByteArray is pdf, then you can directly attach to email. Maybe try setting the filename with correct extension `attachmentBodyPart.setFileName("prueba.pdf");` or  `attachmentBodyPart.setFileName("prueba.txt");`, etc

Comment: I tried to put the extension but didnt worked at all, the file was in the fortmat I set but when I opened it I receive an error. The error was in the bytearray I was sending, I parsed a PDF to Bytearray and try to send it and it's finally working. Thanks for your answer. @Smile